# draw arc in the center of the Canvas

Tags: canvas, android-canvas

This is how I am drawing arc...

First picture shows how currently it draws on canvas always LEFT TOP corner I want to darw
it any of the corner of the canvas example second picture RIGHT|BOTTOM

[image: Current]   [image: what I want]

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(first == null)
        first = new RectF();
    if(second == null)
        second = new RectF();

    if(p == null)
        p = new Path();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paint.reset();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float _X, _Y, radius, innerRadius;
    path.reset();

    float currentAngle =90;
    float currentSweep;
    float padding = 0;


    _X = 150;//getWidth();
    _Y = 150;//getHeight();

    if (_X < _Y) {
        radius = _X;
    } else {
        radius = _Y;
    }
    radius -= padding;
    innerRadius = radius - thickness;

    first.set(_X - radius, _Y - radius, _X + radius, _Y + radius);
    second.set(_X - innerRadius, _Y - innerRadius, _X + innerRadius, _Y + innerRadius);

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    currentSweep = 270;

    p.arcTo(first, currentAngle + padding, currentSweep - padding);
    p.arcTo(second, (currentAngle + padding) + (currentSweep - padding), -(currentSweep - padding));

    canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
    p.close();

}
```

But it always draws in the LEFT TOP corner how can I change this to CENTER and any corner of canvas. I want a flexibility to change location of my arc anywhere in the Canvas.

Please help.

Comment: Doesn't changing _X, _Y change the arc's position? `_X = canvas.getWidth() - radius` & `_Y = canvas.getHeight() - radius` should draw it at the bottom right corner.

Comment: isn't _X and _Y related to bounds of the arc rather then the location?

Comment: I tried doing what you have suggested it is not giving expected result. But I have experimented with it and I think I can achieve it. though I am still confused that how _x and _y translated to location when pass to the parameter to RectF

Comment: Actually _x and _y is the center. The bound is set by the `radius` variable. Look at arguments that are being passed to the `set()` method of `first` and `second`.

Comment: I got an idea thanks for helping me to get into the right direction.

Comment: Ok. No problem. I'll still post a proper answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `_X` & `_Y` variables.

I don't understand why you need this

```
if (_X < _Y) {
    radius = _X;
} else {
    radius = _Y;
}
```

but if you just need the arcs with a constant radius, then you don't need the above code.

Then, you can position it easily using something like

```
//For bottom right
_X = getWidth() - radius;
_Y = getHeight() - radius;

//For top right
_X = getWidth() - radius;
_Y = radius;

//For bottom left
_X = radius;
_Y = getHeight() - radius;

//For center
_X = getWidth() / 2;
_Y = getHeight() / 2;
```